# Remote Control on rooted device

Tags: android, controls, root

I know you need a root access to do Remote Control on Android.

so given it is a rooted device, how do I access screen / inject keys?

Use IWindowManager? But IWindowManager is still hidden on rooted device.

Grant READ_FRAME_BUFFER, INJECT_EVENTS permissions?
Do I then use: 
cat /dev/graphics/fb0 
to grab screenshot?

Comment: I don't think rooting has anything to do with this. You'll need a custom firmware image that will support this.

Answer (score 0):

use adb shell input keyevent 82 or something similar to inject keys